# Is JBPM 5 Session can be reused?

Tags: session, reusability, jbpm

I use JBPM as my workflow engine, but my system is so busy, I may start 500 process per second. JBPM Session is lightweight, but it also cost some time.Can JBPM Session reused? Or how to clear the state of session

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse a session if you want, or there are other strategies like a session per request or per process instance.  The state of a process instance is stored separately in the database, so you don't have to clear a session.

For reaching 500 processes per second (when using persistence), you probably want to run multiple sessions in parallel though, possibly across multiple nodes in a cluster.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need to persistence, I just deal some data use the workflow.Now, i use a session pool to keep the session, but when use the process, the session have some sate, but i don't know how to clear it.